# Im running into an error trying to format the timestamps in my data set

Tags: python, pandas

How would I format this timestamp in python using the pandas library?

```
08.03.2018 00:00:00.000 GMT-0500
```

In my code I keep receiving this error

```
ValueError: time data '08.03.2018 00:00:00.000 GMT-0500' does not match format '%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %z' (match)
```

here is my code

```
pd.to_datetime(data.Date, format='%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %z')
```

Comment: `to_datetime` is pretty smart. You could just do `pd.to_datetime(data.Date)`.

Comment: Try using `%Z` instead of `%z`.